# Using a transaction to roll back saves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

My registration form is complex and fragile. I am trying to use transaction, but it doesn't appear to work the way I think it does.

My intention is to roll back all the saves if something fails down the line. Am I doing this incorrectly?

```
if @little_class_schedule.valid?
  User.transaction do
    if @user.save
      @little_class.user_id = @user.id
      if @little_class.save
        if @location.save
          if little_class_schedule_form_params["schedule_type"].to_i == 2 || @little_class_schedule.save
            if @little_class_session_validation.valid?
              sessions.each do |s|
                if s.save
                  next
                else
                  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
                  render 'class_account_registration/new'
                end
              end
              ApprovalMailer.request_approval(@user, @little_class).deliver
              redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Success!'
            else
              raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
              render 'class_account_registration/new'
            end
          else
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
            render 'class_account_registration/new'
          end
        else
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
          render 'class_account_registration/new'
        end
      else
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        render 'class_account_registration/new'
      end
    else
      render 'class_account_registration/new'
    end
  end
else 
  render 'class_account_registration/new'
end
```

Comment: I think that better to get all information that you need from user, validate it, and only after that save it.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to get a structure in your code and keep it DRY!

Since I don't know what you want to do, I just improved your code. It still isn't the best solution, but since I don't know what you really want to do, I can't change the logic.

```
successful = false

if @little_class_schedule.valid?
    User.transaction do
        if @user.save
            @little_class.user_id = @user.id

            if @little_class.save && @location.save
                if little_class_schedule_form_params["schedule_type"].to_i == 2 || @little_class_schedule.save
                    if @little_class_session_validation.valid?
                        sessions.each do |s|
                            if s.save
                                next
                            else
                                raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
                            end
                        end

                        successful = true
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        unless successful
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
    end
end

if successful
    ApprovalMailer.request_approval(@user, @little_class).deliver_now
    redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Success!'
else
    render 'class_account_registration/new' unless successful
end
```

I haven't tested this code so it could have bugs in it. Please try it out and give us feedback if it works or if not what errors you have.

Hope this helps!

Happy coding :)